# How to Send Multiple Variables Through PayPal IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

This is the flow of customers:

Visit Website -> Fill Out Form With Their Info -> Click "Buy Now" and Checkout with PayPal -> Be Returned Back To The Website -> Use Information Passed From Checkout From to Run `PHP` script on server via `ajax` (assuming the checkout was successful). Well, that's the plan anyways. The problem I am having is figuring out how to actually pass the variables (there are 8 total... array???. I currently have a quick checkout button on the website, which redirects the user away to PayPal to complete the transaction. I've been searching for a good tutorial on YouTube or here at S.O., but have been unsuccessful. Any ideas how I may accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: While the process is understandable, your question is vague. What "variables" are you referring to? I mean, are we talking custom variables for your site/the user? In that case PayPal provides a 'custom' option. If you could elaborate, and provided your current code, that would help.

Comment: @JeffreyKastner yes, custom variables. A mixture of strings and booleans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PayPal form, simply use something like the following for your custom field..

Example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $custom1.','.$custom2.','.$custom3; ?>">
```

or;

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="custom1,custom2,custom3">
```

In short the custom name is accepted by PayPal, and  you would use commas to separate the variables.

PayPal will pass the custom field back to you, in the IPN.

---

**EDIT**:

Here's an example of what you might do with custom:

```
  $custom = $_POST['custom'];
  $pattern = ",";
  $pieces = explode($pattern,$custom, 3);
  // 3 is how many custom fields there are
  $custom1 = $pieces[0];
  $custom2 = $pieces[1];
  if (isset($pieces[2])) {
      //an example checking to see if there is a third custom variable
      $custom3 = $pieces[2];
  }
```

Comment: Great, will give this a try. I'll accept the answer. Any tutorials you know of on how to actually set up a listener?

Comment: @Ethan https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/ has a PHP example of an IPN.

Comment: @Ethan It doesn't, however, show 'custom' (or the full list, for that matter), but you can see an example here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#id08CKFJ00JYK  So, custom would be $custom = $_POST['custom'];

Answer (score 0):

You can use json to pass multiple values via the `custom` variable in PayPal..

Create your values:

```
$custom = array();
$custom['value1'] = "foo";
$custom['value2'] = "bar";
$custom =  json_encode($custom);
```

Then you can `POST` this data to somewhere:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo htmlentities($custom) ?>"/>
```

then get the data from somewhere like this:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['custom']);
echo $data->value2;
```

The output should be `bar`